# Specialize a member function but not entire class

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a template the works with enums

```
template<typename T> class Enumuzaorous : public someclass<T>
{
public:
virtual ~Enumuzaorous() { } ;
virtual void do_this() { ... }
virtual void take_that() { ... }
virtual bool check_something() { return false; } 
T m_value;
}
```

I have many Enums that use this class and one more enum :

```
enum myLovelyEnum
{
today,tomorrow
}
```

For this enum I would like that check_something won't return false but do the following :

```
bool check_something() { return m_value == today; }
```

I can specialize the entire class for the enum, but I would need to copy&paste the implementation of:
 `void do_this() { ... }` `void take_that() { ... }`

Is it possible to specialize only one member function ? I guess not.

Maybe I should Inherit and then specialize ?

What is the correct approach.
Maybe I can call from the specialized do_this, take_that to the generic ones ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why guess? There is a solution presented, does it work as expected? And if not, what is expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Member functions of class template are themselves function templates and can be explicitly specialized:

```
template <>
bool Enumuzaorous<myLovelyEnum>::check_something()
{
     return m_value == today;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've mistakenly over simplified the problem, my Enumuzaorous inherits from something else, is it possible to specialize virtual function ? If no, is there is a way to solve with another approach ?
I've edited the original question

Comment: And I forgot to mention that all the functions are virtual :)

Comment: @OopsUser: I will continue asking what the problem is and what errors you are getting until you come clean. In what way does my solution not work for you?

Comment: I get : "multiple definition of `Enumuzaorous<myLovelyEnum>::check_something()"
 although I only added what you suggested

Comment: @OopsUser: That's a linker error, not a compiler error. Don't put function definitions in headers (only declarations). Explicitly specialized function templates are functions, so you have to obey all the usual rules. (None of this has anything to do with virtual functions or inheritance.) [Demo](https://ideone.com/ouAdgT)

Comment: I'm 100% sure, It works on a small side project I did. But doesn't work in my main project. Unfortunately it is too long/complex to put it all here. So I'm trying to figure out what the source of the problem and then I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can be to use a traits class

```
template <typename T> struct DefaultEnumuzaorousTraits
{
  constexpr static bool check_something_impl(T&) { return false; }
};

template<typename T, class Traits = DefaultEnumuzaorousTraits<T>>
class Enumuzaorous : public someclass<T>
{
   // stuff omitted for brevity
   bool check_something() { return Traits::check_something_impl(m_value); }
};

struct DefaultEnumuzaorousTraits<myLovelyEnum>
{
  constexpr static bool check_something_impl(myLovelyEnum e) 
  { return e == myLovelyEnum::today; }
}
```